# How to remove jsessionid from website address

Tags: java, jsp, jsessionid

I have developed a simple website, without any security feature. The only feature it has is locale, which helps user to visit website in different languages. My question is that why the jsessionid will be added to the website address ? I know it is used to track users but how to remove it from website address?

For example

```
http://mywebsite.com/mywebsite/info.html;jsessionid=AE7AAI54A7ECS5155A5541BEFA7CFA58
```

There is an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558689/how-to-remove-jsessionid-from-html-converted-from-jsp) but I do not know where I should use the suggested code and what does that do ?

Comment: You have a tag but didn't mention in your text: Are you using JSP for your rendering? JSP always forces a session open, even if there's no particularly good reason for it, and using a simpler alternative like [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) might be the easiest solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327631/remove-jsessionid-from-url

Comment: absolutely, that's why I added it as a tag.

Comment: You may also try the `<%@ page session="false" %>` directive. @srkavin, that will work around the problem, but if there's no need to create the session, it's best to suppress it in the first place.

Comment: how about if I use spring security, does deactivating session affect that in anyway?

Comment: Yes, spring-security almost always needs a session, so you cannot deactivate it. You can try to configure your servlet-container (Tomcat?) to disable jsessionid in URLs and use only cookies for storing and sending the jsessionid.